# Error: We are not able to retrieve the keys for function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

> Error: We are not able to retrieve the keys for function XXX. This can
>   happen if the runtime is not able to load your function. Check other
>   function errors.

I get this error when I create a new function and click on " Get function URL". This error shows only after the function is created, seems to work after some time (dozens of minutes or hours)

Function is JavaScript http web hook with parameters. My node runtime is ~1 and plan is Standard.

Comment: This error is not shown after around 5 mins after a new function is created.

Comment: Would you mind [indirectly sharing your function name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)? I can try to look in the logs and see what's happening.

Comment: Sorry for some reason, the error message is back so I can't see the URL. The log for this function is also empty. There is:Session Id: dd77efe3ccc54d2495ad02b35e1276a5 and Timestamp: 2017-09-20T16:02:48.758Z if that helps